# How to close all opening square bracket tags that aren't closed?

Tags: bbcode, square-bracket

Ok, so I have a message, can a regular expression be used to determine if there are square brackets within it, and if so, determine if they aren't closed.

For example, and opening square bracket is like this:  `[code]`

Closing is like this:  `[/code]`

But there are way more than just the code bbc codes that can be within square brackets.

What I'd like to be able to do, is use a variable that contains the entire message, and somehow determine if there are any words within square brackets that do not have a closing tag, which is denoted by:  `[/` the word, and than `]`
Opening tags ofcourse start with `[` the word, and than end with `]`

So, if I have something like this within a variable:

Ok, so here is the overall script.php file with ALL of the Recent Module code in it.  So we start with the Main function for retrieving the $params from the functions parameter...

```
[code]function module_recent($params)
{
   global $context, $txt;

   // Grab the params, if they exist.
   if (is_array($params))
   {
```

It would know that `[code]` was not closed off and add it at the end `[/code]`

But also, if I have something like this:

```
[table]
[tr][td]Hello World[/td][/tr]
[tr][td]This is not closed...
```

It should know that `[table]` and `[tr]` and `[td]` is not closed and it should add the closing tags into it at the end in this order:

`[/td]` and than `[/tr]` and finally `[/table]`

But there are also other tags like `[list][li][/li][/list]`

Would be great if I could populate all of the tags that can be within square brackets within an array and than call upon a function that would check if it has both opening and closing tags, that way it wouldn't effect non-bbc code tags that people put into messages just cause.

Can anyone give me a hand on a Reg. Ex to do this with?  Atleast if someone can help me get started on this that would be excellent.

Thanks guys :)

Comment: Parsing problems are generally better handled with a parser than with a regex.

Comment: How do you suggest I fix this than?  Not familiar with parsers...

Comment: Ok, the problem isn't parsing, the problem is adding closing tags to the body.  The parsing is fine.  This is already done via another program, I just need to close any opening tags within a variable that holds all of the text.  Wondering if I can get any help on this, please?

Comment: Please don't be caught bringing a regex knife to what looks like a turing complete gun fight, its gonna hurt.

Comment: @ NealB, lol.  Perhaps regex isn't the answer than.  But a parser?  I don't understand.  This program already has a parser, but it doesn't handle it without a closing tag, so it needs to have both opening and closing tags which is why I would like to close all opening tags within square brackets.  Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to write a scanner and a parser. The problem of balanced parenthesis is a classic in language theory.

Regular expressions can be used for pattern matching and token extraction. Your problem is a grammatical problem, and you need a parser to solve such problem.

No need for a sophisticated parser in this case. A stack is enough. See the high level algorithm below.

```
enum TokenType{
    StartTag,
    EndTag,
    Text
}

struct Token {
    string Value;
    TokenType TokenType;
}

Token GetNextToken() {
    // returns the next token in the input string or null if end of the string.
}

bool MatchingTags(Token startTag, Token endTag)){
    // check if startTag and endTag match
}

bool CheckTags(){
    Stack stack = new Stack();
    while( (Token t = GetNextToken()) != null )
    {
        switch(t.TokenType){
            case TokenType.StartTag:
                stack.push(t);
            break;
            case TokenType.EndTag:
                Token lastPushed = stack.pop();
                if( ! MatchingTags(lastPushed, t)){
                    return false
                }
            break;
        }
    }
    if (! stack.IsEmpty()){
        return false
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Note: This algorithm also checks proper nesting:   [A][B][/A][/B] is not valid
Note: This is just a code sample to give you an idea. Please refine and adjust it to your programming language/framework.

Comment: Hello, I'm using PHP, so how do I call this parsing algorithm?  BTW, thanks, just not sure how to use this...

Comment: The algorithm is just to give you an idea of the flow. You'll have to implement it in your own word.

PHP arrays can be used as stack. See the functions array_push and array_pop here : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php

PHP is also very rich in string manipulation functions

Finally PHP has all the described control structures (while, swaith, if etc)

Comment: I don't understand any of this code.  shouldn't these be in the form of functions?  Is this a class file of some sort?  I'm not familiar with it.  Need more help here?  How to call any of these functions or whatever they are in my code... dunno?